# How to show someone that offline Windows app I'll send is not malicious?

Tags: windows, offline

I want to send someone an offline app (but would be streamed online by other app like OBS) to use, while wanting to show him that his PC won't be infected (or similar) by that app.

App will rely on some external libraries (seemingly all from trusted sources) and will use mic and camera.

How to approach this so that receiver of app shouldn't worry too much.

I searched and found Docker is pretty secure, but the performance of app is important (especially considering streaming).

Comment: Request your app to be submitted it to the respective Microsoft store (e.g. AppSource) and pass their checks. This way the end-user can at least be reasonably sure it yields from a trusted source.

Comment: @Beltway I am not planning of publishing app publicly (yet at least). I want to send to few people...

Comment: If these people do not know you personally you can't expect them to trust it on your own behalf. You need an authority to verify and establish your app as non-malicious. The most straightforward approach to proof it would be to go open-source.

Comment: @Beltway Okay, but why would open-source be proof, I'm not that experienced in this stuff...? Why does, btw, Verification from Microsoft e.g. make it seem safe, what kind of protocols do they have in place to check that, if you might know? Thanks for suggestions btw! :)